# VB.NET search stucks with MS Access

Tags: vb.net

When I try to make another search order the program gets stuck. 
I mean I can make one search operation, but then program stops working.

This is my code:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Static m As Integer = 0


    If TextBox1.Text = Trim("") Then Exit Sub
    If RadioButton4.Checked = True Then
        ExactSearch()
    ElseIf RadioButton5.Checked = True Then
        GeneralSearch()
    End If

    Conn.Open()
    Dim DataAdapter1 As New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLstr, Conn)
    DataAdapter1.Fill(DataSet1, "Table1")
    Conn.Close()

    TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", DataSet1, "Table1.Name")

    TextBox3.DataBindings.Add("Text", DataSet1, "Table1.DatTim")

    TextBox4.DataBindings.Add("Text", DataSet1, "Table1.mobile")

    DataGridView1.DataSource = DataSet1
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "Table1"

    'Button1.Enabled = False
    If Me.BindingContext(DataSet1, "Table1").Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox("No Result, Please Try Again ")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Button2.Enabled = True
    Button3.Enabled = True
End Sub
Public Sub ExactSearch()
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        SQLstr = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE name = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
    ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
        SQLstr = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE DatTim = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
    ElseIf RadioButton3.Checked = True Then
        SQLstr = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE mobile = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub GeneralSearch()
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        SQLstr = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE name LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"

    ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
        SQLstr = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE DatTim LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"

    ElseIf RadioButton3.Checked = True Then
        SQLstr = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE mobile LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"

    End If
End Sub
```

It gets stuck here

```
TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", DataSet1, "Table1.Name")
```

Please help.

Comment: You may have a good reason for it, but why `textbox.databindings.text` and not `textbox.text`? I mean, it would help us if you were a bit more descriptive of what you're trying to do. :-)

Answer (score 0):

When

```
DataAdapter1.Fill(DataSet1, "Table1")
```

Then

```
TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", DataSet1.Tables("Table1"), "Name")
```

Comment: @user2443661 : have you try this ?